# Unit Test method that blocks thread

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, xunit.net

What is considered the best way to make a UnitTest on a method that waits on something and blocks the thread?
I want to test if the method calls another method, but obviously the test is never ending because the thread waits on another event. I'm using C#, xUnit and Mock
I came up with the idea to throw an exception with the mock when the method is called to end the block. Another idea would be to work with a timeout, but this also doesn't sound right.
What would you consider good practice in this case?

```cs
[Fact]
public void Connect_ConnectAsync_MethodCalled()
{
    // Arrange
    var socketMock = new Mock<IHsmsSocket>();
    socketMock.Setup(x => x.ConnectAsync(It.IsAny<SocketAsyncEventArgs>())).Throws(new Exception("Method called"));

    int bufferSize = 5000;
    int port = 5000;
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
    SocketClient client = new SocketClient(socketMock.Object, bufferSize);

    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

    Exception ex = new Exception("Not called");

    // Act
    try
    {
        client.Connect(endPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ex = e;
    }

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("Method called", ex.Message);

    // Clean up
    client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What about `Mock.Verify`?

Comment: In general yes, but Mock.Verify doesn't help with my blocking thread problem

Comment: why not trigger the event that your thread is waiting on? Then you don't need to blew the stack with an exception, and you can test the side effect with Verify...?

Comment: I think this would also only work with a timeout to allow the method to execute. And it's much more complicated because it's waiting for a response of a socket. This means more dependencies. Which you could of course mock, but as @MikeLimaSierra said working with an exception gives a clearer view on the intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i would go with throwing a specific exception like you do in your example.
This is the easiest way to get right and also the most obvious for any reader of the test.

While a timeout would work just as well, it would have the same effect but really just increase the time it takes to run your test.

Readers of your test might wonder why you are using a timeout in the first place.
It may not be clear, why a specific interval was used for waiting to finish.

I would also rather not throw an `System.Exception` but a specific custom exception like `DummyException` to make clear it is purely for testing and has nothing to do with the actual behavior behind the method call.

Instead of your try-catch block i would also prefer this but that's kinda personal preference.

```cs
var ex = Assert.Throws<DummyException>(action);
Assert.Equal(ex.Message, "Method called");
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please accept it.